# NodeJS GET request working in local machine but not inside remote VM

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api, web-scraping

I am trying to create a simple tool which will hit a specific Facebook page and extract some data. I am using NodeJS for this. I am using inbuilt https module to the GET request. The thing in my local machine it is working fine but inside the VM it is not able to get the response, it is failing every time.

I tried with axios also but it is not working either.

Previously I thought that could be firewall issue but I enabled every thing inside the firewall but then also it is not working. Very strange issue I am facing with this.

What can be the possible reason for this?

Is it Facebook blocking my request? No right? I am sending User-Agent header also but it is not working.

My code looks like below :

```js
const options = {
  hostname: 'www.facebook.com',
  // port: 443,
  path: `/${username}`,
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'user-agent':
      'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6',
  },
};
const request = https.request(options, (response) => {
  let body = '';
  console.log('response : \n' + response);
  response.setEncoding('utf8');

  response.on('data', (chunk) => {
    body += chunk;
    console.log('response on data chunk : \n' + chunk);
  });
  response.on('end', () => {
    console.log('body : \n' + body);
    const arrMatches = body.match(rePattern);
    if (arrMatches && arrMatches.length > 1) {
      resolve(arrMatches[1]);
    } else {
      reject(new Error('Facebook user not found'));
    }
  });
});

request.on('error', (err) => {
  console.log('request error : \n' + err);
  reject(err);
});

request.end();
```

Comment: Hmm..silly question but is everything okay with internet connection on the VM? `ping google.com` works fine? Thanks.

Comment: Obviously it works fine. Done all possible things before posting the question.

Comment: Okay, *failing every time* - what error exactly are you getting? Could you share some more details? Timeout, auth error (but it seems to be anonymous), forbidden?

Comment: my main target is to get the HTML page source code of the Facebook page. I am trying with cURL now but for it also it is failing.

Here is the cURL -v output
https://pastebin.com/3RebQYFw

Comment: We can clearly see there's `HTTP/2 302` redirect being done to the login page.

Comment: Yeah but if you visit from browser it wont redirect. so you are saying its security from facebook side for non-browser scraping?

Comment: Yeah and in my case it does not do the redirect...I don't think it's some security from facebook.